# faster serialization of relatively big TreeMap

Tags: java, serialization

I have a `TreeMap<List<String>, Integer>` with a custom comparator and lots of entries(700k at this point, but it might be more). The List instances are generally short(1-3 entries).

Now using standard serialization takes about 2 minutes time, a custom implementation as below still takes more than a minute.

```
@Override
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    frequencies.clear(); //frequencies is the TreeMap
    int entrySize = in.readInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < entrySize; ++i) {
        int phraseLength =  in.readInt();
        List<String> phrase = new ArrayList<>(phraseLength);
        for(int j = 0; j < phraseLength; ++j) {
            phrase.add((String)in.readObject());
        }
        frequencies.put(phrase, in.readInt());
    }
}
```

How can I make it faster?

Comment: if your phrase length has a limit, you could use a smaller data type for the phraseLength (short or byte).

Comment: did you profile your method to see where it is spending its time?

Comment: Can it be assumed the input is sorted? It might be possible to extend the TreeMap and save the comparator work in this case. Should the list have flex size after init? An array might be more efficient.

Comment: A couple of thoughts come to mind...can you replace your List<String> with a wrapper type that pre-computes whatever work your Comparator is doing?  (How many times is your comparator getting called during your deserialization?)  Is there some degenerate behavior in the TreeMap operating on sorted input (which I'd expect to get from a serialized form)?

Comment: Also, another random thought: how long does it take if you were to copy your TreeMap to a HashMap and back?

Answer (score -2):

I've had a lot of success with this library:

http://tree.phi-sci.com/

http://tree.phi-sci.com/tree.pdf

It's in c++, but I've been able to use it to do very fast tree processing.

Specifically, we had 500,000 records being processed (several passes, operations and calculations) in 300ms.

Comment: Easy, he asked, "how can I make it faster?" He didn't ask, "how can I make it faster in Java?"

Comment: I mean, two minutes versus less than half a second? If he wants to make it faster, wouldn't he at least consider c++ as an option? I had my solution up and running in production in a day. It's not as hard as everyone paints it to be. This library has built-in iterators and tree methods and is very stable.

Comment: rewriting the whole project in C++ is not an option (and neither are JNI bindings)

Comment: You don't have to rewrite the whole thing. Just the computationally-intensive spots. Anyways, even if it's not directly applicable for you, doesn't mean someone else searching later won't opt to give it a try.